# Close queue audit reviews damn you too quickly

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, review-audits

The Close queue audit reviews damn you too quickly.  I have just failed yet another of the audits because, as usual, I want to see what the hell people are doing with their close votes before I decide what to do with my voting.  It's especially problematic with audit questions since it is often less than obvious what the trouble is supposed to be, but I can't accept the question as OK until I know what the criticisms are.

But just for clicking on the close button, you are damned as a "Failure". It should wait until you commit to a close vote before damning you.

Oh, and while I'm at it, I should mention that failing the audit is not something that inspires one to continue the labour of … well, it isn't a labour of love, that's for sure; working the close review queue is hard work and totally unrewarding, and the system adding insult to injury doesn't endear the close queue to me.

Comment: Same problem — still unfixed.  When is the Stack Exchange team going to remove the disincentives to reviewing the close queue?  I loathe the close queue; I work on it as a good citizen; I get castigated for trying to work out what the hell is going on; I get frustrated — very, very frustrated.

Comment: [Close vote review audit flawed - fails without casting vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179651/close-vote-review-audit-flawed-fails-without-casting-vote)

Comment: I have failed a few close review audit because I filter the queue down to a few closely related tag, and a question come up is that clearly a bad question in relationship to these tags. (E.g it is unclear what someone is asking, as the questions just does not make sense when thinking about the given tags.) However it was a review audit that had just had my chosen tags added to it.

Comment: This is now [tag:status-completed], it appears it's just been implemented. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168824/using-the-flag-loophole-to-pass-every-review-audit/231658#231658

Comment: I haven't run across the new behaviour yet, but thank you for implementing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Furthermore I want to see what the new close reasons are and see if any apply to the question before leaving open. But this now counts as "failing an audit."

This question is now marked as "by design," although I don't see how any design could fit this, and Shog9's answer only addresses the use case of peeking at other people's votes, which he argues is invalid and therefore irrelevant. As for my use case here, I don't know how this could possibly be "by design."

FWIW this damages my ability to review questions pretty hard (cannot easily refer to close reasons), so I'm not working on this review queue until this is fixed. Sorry.

Comment: As long as the first step in your process is asking yourself, "should this question be closed *for any reason?*" then this doesn't interfere with your workflow at all. The perfectly-good question you're looking at probably isn't going to match any new or old close reasons, at least not without a lot of squinting. OTOH, if the question sucks and you open the close dialog only to find no matching reason... Well, that's unfortunate too, but at least you're probably not failing an audit.

Answer (score 18):

I still think [you shouldn't be clicking that button at all](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251038/close-queue-audit-reviews-damn-you-too-quickly/251400#251400) if you don't think the question should be closed...

But there are occasionally extenuating circumstances where it is useful to go through the motions (using the built-in dup search, for instance). So [m0sa](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155005/m0sa) came up with a clever solution, which now allows you to go through the entire process of selecting a close reason before deciding whether or not you've passed or failed the audit.

Hopefully, this will be *less* discouraging for the folks reviewing in good faith and no less frustrating for those doing it poorly.

Comment: +1 for the bit *after* the first sentence. btw, is there any work going towards making the review queues more rewarding? I remember some talk about that somewhere.. Can't remember where.

Answer (score -3):

Why should other people's views matter on how you decide to review a question?  **You** are being asked to review the question, not how many people decided to vote to close.

I confess - I've run into this situation a lot while reviewing the Close Vote queue.  I've seen a question that *could* be closed, but I didn't see any real rationale to close it.  There have been one or two (okay, maybe a few hundred) times in which I did actually go to the question to see how other's voted, and let that be the tie breaker.

Then I realized that was wrong.  So, *so* wrong.  I wasn't making the reviews any better; I was probably negatively contributing to the community by letting pile-on close votes get by, as opposed to actually evaluating the question.  I went with the flow instead of with what the review really should've been.

When you're doing a review of a question, you want to look at the question based on its merits alone.  If you think the question is on the edge or borderline, there is no reason not to [skip the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/1079354) and let someone else review it.

Comment: I can't write scathing comments countering the erroneous close votes if I can't see what they're closing them for.  When it isn't an audit review, I can do that without problem.  When it is an audit review, I can't.  And that difference is very, very irritating.  When it happens, I don't go back to the close queue for a few days.  If the SO team really wanted it emptied, they'd make sure there are _no_ speed bumps in people's way.

Comment: Uh, but you *can* see what they're closing them for, @Jonathan - the reason(s) are listed right at the start of the review! "Should this question be closed as: ..."

Comment: That does not give all the details.

Comment: Then click (more) if you want more details.

Comment: @Shog9 I think one other issue is that you can't see the other reasons behind a vote, and something like "Off-topic", which can have varying sub-reasons to it, would be nice to see them beforehand (rather than just manually visiting the question anyhow and looking, or finding out it's an audit because of such regardless). If the system were really made to stop people from being lazy or rushing through without thinking, it shouldn't immediately punish someone for seeking more information I would say. Rather, that should be left to occur for someone who makes an *action*.

Comment: Click "(more)", @Rogue.

Answer (score -8):

> as usual, I want to see what the hell people are doing with their close votes before I decide what to do with my voting

So don't do that.

Look, you've earned the privilege to view pending close votes on any post you want. If you want to use that privilege, I can't tell you to stop and wouldn't want to.

But I can say it's a stupid and unproductive way to *review* questions that are up for closure, and there's no particularly good reason for the system to encourage that behavior *in that context*. You're not asked to review the close votes, **you're asked to review the *question*!** There might not even *be* any close votes. Or they might all be bogus. That doesn't mean the question shouldn't be closed though, and that's the question you're asked to answer: should the question you're shown be closed or not?

If you don't care to answer *that question*, then don't. The world ain't gonna end if you go do something that you enjoy doing more.

Oh... And when the problems with a given question are *so subtle* that you can't see them without the aid of someone else's close reason, then chances are you should either be skipping the review entirely, or answering "Leave Open".

Comment: I agree. Pile-on voting sucks.

Comment: Usually, I'm trying to work out why the hell people have voted and what they've voted because I don't agree with the close vote, but I may be missing something that would change my mind.  I work **hard** on close votes; they're not something that I undertake lightly.  And I don't pile-on vote, dammit.  I try to assess everything and the way I do that is by looking at everything, but it is too painful to open up the original question each damn time I'm in the review queue.  So, if it happens much more, I shall simply leave close queue to people with thicker skins than I've got.

Comment: "You're not asked to review the close votes, you're asked to review the question!"

Comment: Ok, you're advising me not to go through the close review queue. Fair enough — I've been following your advice for a while — but if everybody follows your advice, we have a problem. The problem with your answer is that it ignores the fact that some close reasons are indeed subtle, especially the typo reason on SO and the is-a-bug and unsupported-version reasons on AU. Other reasons invite me to berate the closer, and for that I need to know what the reason is. It would help if there weren't a bunch of unrelated close reasons for on-topic questions hidden under the heading “off-topic”.

Comment: I'm not advising you to not do anything, other than use a certain tool for a purpose it was clearly not designed for, @Gilles. If you don't want to use it for the task it was built to do, then don't - that's your choice though. If everyone decides they don't want to use it that way, then we can get rid of it and I can do something more productive.

Comment: Bad day at the office?

Comment: Spent the day hanging siding, then this. So... Yes ;-p