# Answers that say "I had this problem too" but still attempt to answer the question

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts, me-too-answers

In the VLQ queue I fairly often come across answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23292844/2846923):

> I had the same error but fixQualifiedLibraryPaths would not solve it. In fact libdl.so and libm.so were missing from my local rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf directory (there was only libdl.a ans libm.a). I copied the 2 files from yhe Raspberry Pi and was able to make the compilation sucessfully.

It looks like it should be deleted because of the first sentence, "I had the same error but fixQualifiedLibraryPaths would not solve it." People see that first sentence and think *Oh, it's one of those "I'm having this problem too" answers*. In fact, that answer got three recommend deletion votes. However, it *does* attempt to answer the question; the rest of the answer is the equivalent of: "The problem for me was [whatever], so [whatever] solved it."

I see a few things that could be done:

1. Delete it (Recommend Deletion)
2. Do nothing (Looks Good)
3. Edit it to remove the first "I had this problem too."
4. Edit it from "I had this problem too, this is what was causing it, here's what fixed it for me." to "This is what is (or could be?) causing your problem, here's how to (possibly?) fix it."
5. Something else?

Which of those should I do when I encounter these types of answers in the VLQ—or just when I'm browsing questions?

Comment: It refers to the solution given in the other answer. So I'd say an edit to clarify that would be the way to go.

Comment: As far as they still try to answer the question, I usually do nothing with them untouched. However, the `I'm having this issue too` are useless and probably it's ok removing that statement, too.

Comment: I personally think answers like that are good. If there are multiple possible causes, I would think we would want to leave other possible answers to the problem. Just because it doesn't solve OP's problem, doesn't mean it won't help some future seeker.

Comment: The answer is rather low quality, even if it contains accurate information. Two-thirds of the post describe a "me too" problem, and the solution is contained only in the final sentence. I agree with Bart that editing may be the right choice, but a clear, authoritative answer would have been less susceptible to closing than this one.

Comment: I've had a few instances, where the answer said "I did this and that but none worked", but one of those worked for me. They tried a few things which didn't work for them, but one of them fixed my issues.

Comment: Personally, I think it's relevant that they actually had and dealt with the problem before. It's two different things to answer a question from experience or from base principles and reasoning. I would want to know an answer came from experience because then, at least if our problems were actually the same (instead of just having the same symptoms), I have 1) a way to verify we have the same problem and 2) a solution.

Comment: I think there's a big difference between "I'm having this problem too" and "I had this problem too".  The first (present continuous tense) is the trouble-maker; the person has the problem and probably hasn't solved it.  The second (past) tense is not a problem; it indicates that the person answering really does know what the OP is dealing with (because they had the problem too) and they now know a solution — which follows.  So, the answer should be up-voted or left open; it is (or should be) perfectly permissible to report that you've encountered and solved the problem posed in the question.

Comment: A question like this came up in a review queue as an audit.  It attempted to answer the question so I clicked No Action Needed and failed the audit.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I agree, though it depends on who's writing. Many non-native speakers have major issues with tense, and will write "I have" for "I had" or vice versa. (Or even more confusing things. I once posted an answer and got a comment along the lines of "I already did that, and it worked! Thank you!", where "I already did that" was, I eventually realized, a non-native attempt at "I have now done that".) So it's not so much a matter of whether the sentence is in the present tense or the past tense, as of whether it is *supposed* to be in the present tense or the past tense. :-P

Comment: @NobodyNada: I have a separate discussion on the Close queue being to quick to condemn you for doing what you normally do.  See: [Close queue audit reviews damn you too quickly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251038/close-queue-audit-reviews-damn-you-too-quickly).  So far, I don't seem to be making any progress in persuading the powers-that-be that the way people _actually_ do reviews is different from the way that they think people _should_ do reviews.

Comment: Please be careful when clarifying/editing answers. Your #4 suggestion is, in fact, not a correct interpretation; the danger is that your suggestion is changing the answer to assume that the OP's problem is exactly what the answerer says, when so often at StackOverflow it is (actually) not.

Comment: I have to agree with @TylerH. A key factor is whether or not the new 'answer' is addressing the same problem. Often I see it is a related problem but not the same. Problems that are not the same shouldn't, IMO, be there even if similar. If it is a different solution to the very same problem, it is potentially viable.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I'm thinking that the best course of action would be to remove (or at least reword) the "*I'm having this problem too*" from the answer.

Far too many people appear to see this and then stop reading as they seem to immediately flag the answer as "not an answer", when it clearly is an attempt at an answer to the question.

Removing this will then enable people to "see" the answer for what it is and react accordingly. It will also hopefully reduce the number of pile on flags on posts.

Oh, and don't forget to mark any "not an answer" flags as invalid.

Comment: It would probably become a non-issue if the "I had this problem too..." statement was simply moved to the bottom of the answer as a parenthetical aside.

Comment: Our humans are behaving too much like robots.

Comment: People need to just watch what they're doing and make sure they're flagging things correctly.  People need to be banned from Stack Exchange for flagging things recklessly.

Comment: I actually like it when a post begins with something like *"I had this problem too..."* because it tells me that at least one other person had the exact same problem and solved it using whatever follows. Even if a post has 0 votes, I'll still consider it because it's a proven solution for at least one person.

Comment: Being banned seems harsh, but I think temporary removal of flagging abilities seems reasonable. Permanent removal if they pass some generous amount of suspensions. I've never really understood the action of only reading the first sentence and assuming the rest of the post. It's like hearing the first couple words of a sentence and then leaving.

Comment: @Rachel: If only we had more people who think like you do.

Comment: What about changing "I'm had this problem too and I did ..." to "I solved that problem by..."?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I completely disagree! :) *Robots* are those who are able to read everything. We *humans* need to use shortcuts and read the clues and hints only instead of the whole because we are not so perfect as the robots to really go through everything.

Comment: @DoubleDouble it's the TL;DR attention span issue. Sad really.

Comment: @AlfonsoJiménez I would suggest posting that as an answer. I would much rather see that done than have these details removed entirely. To me, knowing the Answerer faced the same issue and solved it is relevant information and should not be removed.

Comment: Tbh though this isn't really a problem with the answer but with people wanting their review badges as quickly as possible, the read the first bit and then assume the rest. There are random checks for when someone is doing that but it still doesn't solve the problem entirely.

Comment: @Sammaye - yes it is a problem with the reviewers, but educating all of them would be hard. Far easier to remove the problem at source.

Comment: Reword as "The solution I used when I ran into this problem myself was... (tl;dr summary)"  Then describe attempts at other answers, diagnosis of why they failed, as well as the complete explanation of what did work, preferably with the conditions under which it can be expected to work for others.

Comment: Completely agree with @Rachel If someone has had a similar/same problem and they managed to solve it, I'd be very much interested in knowing what they did. Removing/Deleting that answer does seem to be wrong here.

Comment: *"when it clearly is an attempt at an answer"* - did you mean *"when it is an attempt at answering the original question"*? I believe this makes a difference.

Answer (score 25):

I don't think it should be either deleted or edited as described.  When I'm reading an answer, "I had this problem too" indicates that the poster actually had the problem and solved it, while editing it can make the answer look like it is based on speculation.  Doing nothing when browsing and marking it as looking good in queue seems to me the appropriate action.

Comment: I would say editing "I had this problem too" into "I solved the problem as following:" transports the same message.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I agree that edit would work well.  I clarified my answer to refer just to the proposed edits in the question.