# Understanding how to handle "I had same problem" answers

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, moderation

Long ago, I opened [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317072/google-maps-api-v3-svg-markers-disappear). It was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16376850/1238965) and accepted.

Months, and even years later, 4 additional answers were posted. I tried to summarize here what they are:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20072546/1238965 - *I had the same problem... I tried (what was suggested in the accepted answer), it worked...*
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40089202/1238965 - *I had kind same trouble...* - Note: It was obviously a different problem which was solved by a different solution.
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45653915/1238965 - *Thanks to the accepted answer, it works...*
4. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51183496/1238965 - *I had same problem with React...* - Note: this suggests a different solution, but no example/proof is given that it would have solved the original question.

I flagged all 4 above answers as *Not an answer* and I believe I should not have raised that flag for [answer #4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51183496/1238965). But what about the other 3 answers?

All my flags were declined, except for [answer #3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45653915/1238965) where it still shows as *disputed*.

So my questions are: should I flag such answers, and if yes, which flag should I raise? And if not, why should I not?

Comment: Attempts to answer are still answers. That said, you could claim the answers duplicate a previous answer [if so, it appears not a case of plagiarism with malice]. For this you would need to raise a custom flag explaining why it's a duplicate answer. Don't expect success: mods aren't subject matter experts, and the bar to prove an answer is a duplicate is high (read: mostly copy-paste).

Comment: most important is to downvote the answers. The ones < 0 can then be deleted by 20K-ers. Leaves the one with +5. Try a custom flag as @jpp suggests but you need to provide all context and arguments for the mod why they need to delete that answer.

Comment: see also: [Answers that say “I had this problem too” but still attempt to answer the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252170/839601)

Comment: That is a rather flawed answer.  You need to edit it to get rid of the "works for me, but try this" approach.  As-is it is far too likely to draw "somebody is wrong on the Internet" posts from users that have the same problem.

Comment: All right, while I believe the 2 duplicates only answer half of my questions, I see now that some clean-up was done on these answers so thanks for that.