# Audit review failed too quickly

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I failed this [audit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4668561) because I clicked on *flag*. In fact, I saw this question some days ago, so I was thinking *this is a duplicate because this question already appeared before*. So I wanted to use the built-in search tool which appears when we click on *Flagging > Closing > Duplicate* to check if it was a duplicate or not. But the system detected this as a failed audit before I performed any real action.

So I suggest to declare that an audit failed only after the user perform the flagging action to the end, not just because the user opened the *flag* menu.

Comment: Is [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251038/close-queue-audit-reviews-damn-you-too-quickly) a duplicate?

Comment: @rene: I already saw this other question, it's different since the OP wanted to *see what the hell people are doing with their close votes*.

Comment: Question on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207735/audits-and-the-canonical-question-bug

Comment: @OneKitten: thanks for the link. According to  [Meta hasn't changed at all](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251375/2257664), this question is not a duplicate of the other one on MSE, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @n.1 I did exactly the same as you the other day, wanting to use the built in search - it even gives you a list of suggestions too.

Comment: You said a couple of years ago that this wasn't a dupe, but I think it is. Moreover, that dupe is marked [meta-tag:status-completed] for *precisely* [the reason you mention here in this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259935/366904): *"But there are occasionally extenuating circumstances where it is useful to go through the motions (using the built-in dup search, for instance)."*

Comment: @CodyGray thanks, I didn't check the possible duplicate since I posted the question. I'm not sure to understand, is this problem fixed and won't happen in the future?

Comment: Well, that's what it looks like to me. I don't know for sure. I was kind of wondering if you had revisited this question because you'd failed another audit for the same reason.

Comment: @CodyGray It looks like this has been fixed: "now allows you to go through the entire process of selecting a close reason before deciding whether or not you've passed or failed the audit". I'll close this question as a duplicate. Thanks.