# Why did I fail this audit?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, disputed-review-audits

I just failed an audit on ([Is it required to explicitly list default parameters when using template template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017466/is-it-required-to-explicitly-list-default-parameters-when-using-template-templat)).

The question was originally marked with an incorrect close reason. However, a comment on the question pointed to an answer to a similar question, followed by the OP's comment "@dyp Yes, this answer seems to about my problem. The CWG issue #150 looks interesting. Great find, thank you! :) –  Michał W. Urbańczyk 2 days ago"

I examined the linked answer and its question, and felt it was sufficiently similar to the new question to justify voting the close the new question as a duplicate, which would point readers to the "Great find" answer and associated comments.

I do not understand why this is an audit fail. I definitely was paying attention.

Comment: The question is open, therefore _technically_ your decision to vote to close it was wrong (i.e. not what the audit expected you to do to pass it). That said, the audit system is far from perfect, and all of us have failed an audit or two.

Comment: I am sufficiently frustrated with the audit system that I am seriously considering stopping reviewing. Even when I pass an audit, the response is condescending and lacks any apology for taking up my time and effort on a non-issue.

Comment: The system doesn't work that way. It is a highly upvoted question with no downvotes. So it is used as an audit question to see whether the reviewers are paying attention. The system didn't expect a close vote. What you can do though, is click the link to the question and cast your close vote there, not in the review section.

Comment: It is indeed a very good question. There is no doubt or argument about that. The issue is whether it is a duplicate of another good question, something that may not have been apparent when the votes were cast.

Comment: @Patricia, what is condescending in *Congratulations!*?

Comment: I'll just leave this here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Compare to something like "This was an audit. Thank you for completing it correctly. We are sorry this took some of your time and effort away from actual issues, but the audits are unfortunately necessary to maintain quality.". I already know I'm paying attention, so there is no need to tell me that.

Comment: @Patricia, I can see your point. I personally prefer cheer-ups to apologies, but YMMV. Anyway, since *audits are unfortunately necessary to maintain quality* (and indeed they do), the time spent passing audits does not really constitute *effort away from actual issues*, does it?

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks for the link. That idea would greatly reduce the frustration in this situation, where to go on reviewing I'm supposed to lie by clicking "I understand" on something I disagree with.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256727/automatic-review-audit-commenting-as-duplicate-leads-to-fail and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179651/close-vote-review-audit-flawed-fails-without-casting-vote/179770#179770 regarding duplicates. And https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252363/audit-review-failed-too-quickly too.

Comment: Also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207735/audits-and-the-canonical-question-bug.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - Audits are necessary, due to the scale of review abuse we'd have otherwise, but the heuristics do fail from time to time. Non-answers and spam get voted up by sock puppets, people disagree over whether or not questions should be closed, etc. Having a means of contesting this would allow us to keep the audits while offering good reviewers like yourself an out for the occasional bad audits.

Comment: Indeed - it would be really nice if there were a way to contest an audit *from* the audit page. Like, send a message to a moderator: if they agreed with your assessment, it would remove the audit fail, otherwise it would add a few more fails to your list so you'd be closer to getting review banned. :p

Comment: @neminem Review banning is a meaningless penalty - I am seriously considering stopping reviewing because of the current audit system. Badges and reputation points have no use to me - my non-SO qualifications are such that if I were not retired and were applying for a job I doubt if SO would even get a mention in my resume. I do this only to try to help other programmers.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan For you it is. For me it isn't - I don't do it to put on my resume, that'd be silly. I do it to help out the site, because I love that this site exists and is going strong (I remember the pre-SO days, where you could only find answers on forums, or expert-sexchange, or *shiver* yahoo answers). So it bugged me all kinds of ways getting one of those temp review-bans a while back for the bad luck of getting a handful of dumb audits close enough in a row. (That and it's a great way to take your mind off work for a couple minutes without getting in trouble :p.)

Comment: @neminem I only see value in the site to the extent that it serves my aim of helping programmers. Sometimes it seems that it is supposed to be a work of art whose purity is more important than its usefulness.