# Review audit dispute: Isn't this a duplicate?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, disputed-review-audits

I failed review audits a few times, and often mildly disagree. But this one just seems blatantly wrong:

[Array syntax in Java: what is the significance of the [] location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239773/array-syntax-in-java-what-is-the-significance-of-the-location)

I identified it as a duplicate of this question:

[Difference between int[] array and int array[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129178/difference-between-int-array-and-int-array)

I was actually pretty happy about finding what I consider to be an almost 100% duplicate. But the system said that I was wrong, and should have voted to leave the question open.

Comment: I will agree that the 2 questions are duplicates, but only if `String` and `int` declaration in Java are the same (I don't think there's a reason they would be different, I just don't know Java). That being said, the accepted answer on the first (duplicate) question better explains the situation than the accepted answer of the second (even thou a similar answer is available on the second question as well). And I would think that an emphasis should be put on both the question and the existing answers, not only on a question. Maybe that's why the audit failed.

Comment: Was the question shown in the audit as closed for a different reason?

Comment: I think this question may be a duplicate of my question (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258646/1798593). The audit presented a duplicate as closed for some other, invalid, reason and then failed me for noticing the duplicate and marking it as such. It appears to be a rather annoying bug in the audit system.

Comment: It is definitely a duplicate - I closed it as such.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: If I understand the question you linked directly, this was a different case. In my case, the audit question was considered a good question, even though it was a question that had been asked multiple times before. I failed the audit because I was trying to cast a close vote with a "duplicate" reason.

Comment: @RetoKoradi That was exactly the situation I hit. The question was well-written and on-topic with upvotes. It was presented to me as a review question with a made-up close reason, so I was expected to vote to keep it open. Instead, I voted to close it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My Java is very limited, but yes, it would appear to be a duplicate.  The fact that one is talking about `String` and the other is talking about `int` is inconsequential.

But review audits do not handle duplicates at all so you will never see an audit post that wants to you close as a duplicate.  If you ever get a post that you think it an audit, you need to avoid the temptation to vote to close it as a duplicate from the review queue.  Instead click through to see the question directly and then vote to close it there.  You can then click leave open in the review queue (if you are positive it is an audit) or skip if you aren't.

---

Audits are automatically selected based on a number of criteria.  The exact criteria depends on which review queue, but for the Close (and Reopen) queue the criteria is (per Shog's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168366/failed-a-reopen-question-audit-sure-looks-like-not-a-real-question-to-me/168372#168372)):

> - Recently asked
> - Score between 5 and 15 (inclusive)
> - Never locked, migrated, or deleted
> - No close votes or downvotes, ever (only for close/reopen audits)
> - (On Stack Overflow) at least 100 views

So it ended up getting selected because no one voted to close it as a duplicate and no one even downvoted it.

Comment: I think the audit system needs to be changed to accept closing as a duplicate as rejecting the invalid close reason it constructed.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan the current design is not ideal but it's not really as simple as that.  If this was implemented, you give a robo-reviewer a free pass on every audit because all they have to do is go and vote to close **every** question they find as a duplicate and they will be 100% guaranteed of passing every audit

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan the better solution is the one that Brad Larson has as a [comment on your question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258646/why-did-i-fail-this-audit#comment37337_258646)

Comment: I strongly agree with Brad Larson's suggestion. However, I also think that marking as a duplicate should be treated as rejecting other close reasons, such as "too broad". Robo-duplicate marking could be controlled by statistical means - being the first to find a duplicate for a question that is in the review queue for other reasons should be relatively rare.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Except if they vote to close every question they find as a duplicate, pretty soon they'll probably be getting mod attention for a ton of invalid flags. (I'm assuming here that there aren't going to be too many people getting 3k points and *then* starting to robo-review.)

Comment: @neminem we're not talking about flags, but close votes, which you can't review until you are at 3K from the close vote queue.  So until they get caught, they can do real damage and after they get caught, it can take a while to clean up the mess.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Ah, I was assuming you were talking about audits in general; I guess I missed the tag stating it was close vote audits specifically. Are there really people waiting to get to 3k rep before then doing stupid things like that with it?

Comment: @neminem some users are a little to motivated to earn little shiny bits of pixels on their displays.

Comment: @psubsee2003: I had no indication that this was an audit. It didn't even cross my mind. I looked at it, and thought "this looks so basic, it **must** have been asked before". So I did a search, first found a few quite similar question, and then the one that I identified as an exact duplicate. Going to the question directly, and cast the duplicate close vote there seems convoluted, but it might be the best approach. Casting duplicate votes is a very common case when working on the close queue, and not being able to do that there directly will make the process much slower.

Comment: @Retro I understand. It is one of the biggest limitations in the audit system. Ideally if more people vote on dups instead of answering it would be less of a problem (ironic since I answered this dup). If you come up with a concrete idea on how to fix without hurting the review system, It would be well received

Comment: @psubsee2003: Yes, based on the background, it certainly sounds like a recognized problem. I also thought it was ironic to get a question about dups closed as a dup. But since the original question did not have an answer, I appreciate that you provided one here.

Comment: @RetoKoradi A helpful hint...  any time you come across a seemingly well written question in a close vote review, always click through and look at the original post.  If the score doesn't match the review and you don't  see any close votes, then changes are it is an audit.