# Review audit: "Recommend Deletion" triggers too early

Tags: bug, status-declined, disputed-review-audits

When reviewing LQPs or Close votes which are not obviously low quality at first sight, I sometimes click “Recommend Deletion” or “Close”, *only to see* what previous voters might have spotted.

Clicking the Close button in such a case *does not* mean that I intend to actually vote for closing. It means that I'm trying to get more information to find out what could be wrong with the post.

Now this got me fail a review of an obviously great answer. While reviewing, I thought: “What could be wrong with an answer that received *+300 bounty*?”. So I clicked “Recommend Deletion” – bam, fail.

In my opinion, “Recommend Deletion” audits should only trigger after the vote was actually submitted. It's not like an edit, where the audit would let the reviewer spend several minutes improving the post until he/she learns that it was only an audit.

**Update** (thanks @gnat): This observation apparently applies only to audits on LQP *answers*, but not on LQP *questions*, which is even more confusing.

(See also this related Meta discussion: [Audit review failed too quickly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252363/audit-review-failed-too-quickly))

---

Not enough, this failed audit brought me a review ban. As I knew that this was bound to happen some day, I've been collecting strange failed audits.

I know, I know … downvote the original posts etc. … but there are so many bad posts with extremely high upvotes, which are used for reviews. It's really annoying, because a failed review implies that you're doing sloppy reviews on purpose or at least negligently (“Stop and Listen!”).

So I decided to post a selection of some strange failed audits for the enjoyment of the community. Have a look at those and decide how you'd have voted.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6002574

https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/6041099

https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/6048125

https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/6111377

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6142243 (really great one)

These are only the real WTFs; I had some edge cases, too. (Edge cases are reviews that are not strictly compliant with the [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), but are usually well-received and not sanctioned.)

And, I admit, some of my reviews could have used a bit more attention, and failing the audit could have been avoided.

Comment: In close vote review audits [you'll have to actually select a close reason and click Vote before passing / failing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179770/165773). As for LQ reviews, clicking _recommend deletion_ in these doesn't show prior recommendations - I just tested that

Comment: @gnat: Interesting, I could swear I saw prior recommendations on both LQP *and* Close. Unfortunately can't test right now. ;) In this case, maybe I have confused the two review tools. Then, the question would be: Why can't I see previous votes in the LQP queue.

Comment: Close indeed does that in LQP (for questions), it's _Recommend Deletion_ (for answers) that doesn't

Comment: That explains a lot. Thanks for researching!

Comment: I believe *Recommend Deletion* doesn't actually even care which option you choose; it only shows the comment.  So if you don't see a comment, you won't get any more information by clicking *Recommend Deletion* (LQP queue).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Don't fail LQP review audits just for looking at the deletion popup](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302336/dont-fail-lqp-review-audits-just-for-looking-at-the-deletion-popup)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, clicking Recommend Deletion doesn't give you any additional information. It just lets you select a comment to leave for the benefit of the author. Which is a completely optional step. If a previous reviewer (or anyone else) *has* left a comment, you'll see it below the post - without having to click anything. You *won't* see it in the dialog. So if you're clicking "Recommend Delete" reflexively in hopes of finding something, you're just wasting your time - **stop**.

Even for Close / "Recommend Close", the click is a waste of time - the close reason(s) are displayed by default right at the top-left of the review page:

[image: This question has been flagged as...]

If you haven't yet memorized what the various close reasons mean, you can even expand that section by clicking "(more)":

[image]

The system remembers whether or not you expanded the reasons, so even if you *always* want to see what folks have voted for, you don't need to waste a click on *every single review* - just expand it once and go on your merry way.

There's an additional advantage to this as well: in addition to the close reasons previously *voted* for, it lists any reasons that have been *flagged* by low-rep users. This can be particularly useful when a low-rep user has identified a duplicate question:

[image]

We tried to do as much as possible to cram relevant information on the default view for reviews; try to get in the habit of using it, as it will make reviewing faster and probably improve the accuracy of your results.

Comment: For the record, if you expand the close reasons and review an audit, the close reasons will contract again.

Comment: @Shog9: Thanks for the detailed feedback. I think that in the situation, which the question is mainly referring to, I was so astonished to see an answer which won a +300 bounty in the moderation queue that I subconciously tried to find out what could be wrong with it at all, thereby confusing the moderation tools.

Comment: I have to slightly disagree with the statement that all information is visible in the box at the top of the page. When there's an “off-topic” vote, the actual vote reason is hidden in the second level and only seen when selecting off-topic as a close reason.

Comment: Even then, it's one click for "(more)", two for close->ot, @lxg

Comment: Ok, I never realized that it works like this. Talk about learning the hard way.