# Don't fail LQP review audits just for looking at the deletion popup

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queues, review-audits, low-quality-posts

I've just failed a [Low Quality Post review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9134850) audit.

I clicked "Recommend Deletion" but *not* to make a recommendation, only to read the deletion reasons description (I do this often, to confirm and check that a deletion recommendation is appropriate in specific case).

As this was an audit, I failed because the audit takes my clicking on "Recommend Deletion" as my actual final choice.

My suggestion is to make it so we only fail an *audit* when we have chosen an actual deletion option and "clicked Submit".

Comment: I think this has been asked before, but I think it is a reasonable request. I too click "flag" to see what flags we have today - without the intention to flag, but the descriptions and pages they link to change sometimes. You should be able to open the popup without failing an audit.

Comment: @CodeCaster *often*? Errr... not really...

Comment: @CodeCaster that is exactly what I want to be fixed.

Comment: @Jon well sometimes then. My point still stands.

Comment: [Here's the cross-site meta question about this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179651/close-vote-review-audit-flawed-fails-without-casting-vote) (though it's about the Close poup, essentially the same).

Comment: Reason of downvoting please.

Comment: Going by [Shog9's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179770) that says: *This should now be fixed, insofar as you'll have to actually select a close reason and click Vote before passing / failing the audit.* - this would make more sense as a **feature-request** requesting the same behaviour for the review queue dialogs...

Comment: @VictorPolevoy I've reworded your question to fit the feature-request you edited as. I think the info about your ban and other things was unnecessary for a feature-request, but of course feel free to re-edit or roll back. (I've also edited my answer to suit your FR)

Comment: @James Thanks for edition. While it is okay at this moment, but actually I want to be unbanned too.

Comment: I'm not sure what the official process is with asking to be unbanned, but it's for a different question. Don't mix too many things in one question, or people won't be able to vote/discuss on one single thing.

Comment: There is a common misconception that the list presented on "Recommend Deletion" page is a list of "deletion reasons". *It is not*. Delete votes are not classified by reasons, like close votes are. The items listed within LQ review are only *comment templates* provided for your convenience, should you want to use them. The default selection is to use none of them.

Comment: @NormalHuman Delete reasons *are* classified by reasons, the specific delete reason valid for the post being reviewed - otherwise clicking the "Recommend Deletion" would require no further action. As per my answer, there are reasons to view deletion reasons before choosing a "final" outcome. User might view delete reasons and conclude they were wrong and there is no delete reason which fits, so choose another option, or "Skip".

Comment: @James Clicking "Recommend Deletion" _requires_ no further action. There is a prompt for optional, additional action: leaving a comment for the benefit of the author of the post.

Comment: @NormalHuman you are wrong. It requires an action selection (comment or not) and it is cancelable. Audit should fail only on non-cancelable actions!

Comment: To elaborate, I think clicking an "I'm Done!" would suffice as well.

Comment: The phrase "Just because you're on a diet, doesn't mean you can't look at the menu" comes to mind.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett More specifically, you *need* to look at the menu to see if the food is suitable for your specific diet...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry for the long turn-around. I missed that case while I was doing the review audit mocks for the close & flag popups, since the option only shows up for answers. I stumbled upon this bug report/feature request by skimming through the [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) bug list.

The fix will be deployed in the next build (build rev `2015.9.23.3710` on MSE/MSO, `2015.9.23.2840` on sites).

Comment: Unfortunately I've lost my enthusiasm in reviewing posts. I had 2 much ban for this issue :( Thanks for fixing it anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that @VictorPolevoy, I hope that one day you'll reconsider

Comment: Cool, looks like SOUP is actually working the way I hoped it would! :) BTW, next time you fix something I've kluged up a fix for in SOUP, could I please ask for a quick comment ping? Otherwise, if it's someone else's bug report / feature-req, I might miss it and not realize immediately that I should remove the fix from SOUP. I do *try* to code SOUP so that leaving in redundant fixes *should* cause no problems, but [sometimes unexpected things can happen](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307845/error-in-low-quality-posts-queue-when-recommending-deletion). :/

Answer (score 43):

EDIT as you've changed your question to a feature request.

---

### I agree

We *usually* know which "first stage" option is a valid and final outcome just by looking at the review:
"Looks OK | Edit | Recommend Deletion | Skip"

However, there are good arguments in favour of needing to see deletion reasons before being able to choose one of the "first stage" options:

1. Check if a duplicate exists (we might believe we remember one exists etc)
2. User new to reviewing is not familiar with the delete reasons and
   wants to check if one fits
3. A seasoned user has forgotten the *exact / specific* close reason
   wording and wants to double check
4. We all review differently, it doesn't mean we are doing it wrong
5. We might have clicked "Recommend Deletion" by accident (whether we
   should be "more careful" or otherwise, we shouldn't fail an audit on
   this)

Apart from (5), in any of the above (and likely more), the reviewer viewing those deletion reasons for the sake of "checking" (and it not being their final review decision) means they're are actively taking an interest in the review and being conscientious, trying to  decide how to *best* review.

So an *audit* failing us on not robo-reviewing and taking an *active* interest in our options is pretty unfair.

Comment: Well, there's an important difference between close-reasons and delete-comments: The former are obligatory, the latter optional, not selecting one often being best. Now I'm not sure anymore what happens when trying to comment manually before choosing either disposition...

Comment: I am confused - your answer is more as a discussion-like however I want an answer from one of the StackOverflow developers. So I just upvoted your answer but not marked it as accepted.

Comment: It's a feature request so anyone can "answer" to voice their opinion on the requested feature - whether to agree or not, and point out their reasons etc. I pointed out various reasons in favour of your proposal which are not presented in your proposal. Then users can vote on that opinion, and we get a varied view of what users think :).

Comment: This answer points out a deeper flaw (and one that is already well known) with the audit system - audits should be *undeniably* easy to discern, as they are pretty much an anti-robot system, less of an anti-not-good-at-reviewing system. If a flag is questionable, then it shouldn't ever be in the audit system.

Comment: @Qix: There are FRs for manual audit-selection. Look them up, and why they were declined. (There's also a good one for better disputing of failed audits...)

Answer (score 6):

This would not be hard to implement.  In fact, here's a patch against [review.en.js](http://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/review.en.js) to do it:

```js
--- review.en.js    2015-08-13 23:41:36.922833226 +0300
+++ review.en.new.js    2015-08-13 23:50:30.390827172 +0300
@@ -4545,11 +4545,6 @@
             taskReviewed(taskResultTypeIds.LooksGood);
         }
         else if (action == taskResultTypeIds.RecommendDeletion) {
-            if (isAudit) {
-                taskReviewed(taskResultTypeIds.RecommendDeletion);
-                return;
-            }
-            
             if (showDeleteComments) {
                 loadDeleteDialog(taskResultTypeIds.RecommendDeletion);
             } else {
@@ -4557,13 +4552,10 @@
             }
         }
         else if (action == taskResultTypeIds.Delete) {
-            if (isAudit) {
-                taskReviewed(taskResultTypeIds.Delete);
-                return;
-            }
-
             if (showDeleteComments) {
                 loadDeleteDialog(taskResultTypeIds.Delete);
+            } else if (isAudit) {
+                taskReviewed(taskResultTypeIds.Delete);
             } else {
                 $('.review-content div.post-menu a#delete-post-' + currentPostId).click();
             }
@@ -4599,6 +4591,12 @@
             })

             $('#delete-question-form').submit(function () {
+                if (isAudit) {
+                    $popup.trigger("closePopups");
+                    taskReviewed(taskResultTypeId);
+                    return false;
+                }
+                
                 var $form = $(this);

                 // no double submitting please
```

I also managed to come up with a user script fix to "monkey-patch" this feature in; it's currently included in the development branch of [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup), and, assuming it doesn't cause any unexpected side effects, will be part of the next stable SOUP release (v1.34).  It should be noted that the user script version is rather more awkward, mainly because the way the SE review code is written doesn't provide many opportunities for other code to access its internals.  Its effect should be exactly the same, though.

Also worth noting is that this fix does expose a different inconsistency in the review interface: the deletion reason popup is only brought up for low quality *answers*, whereas for questions, clicking the "Recommend deletion" button immediately submits the vote.  For users with deletion privileges, I *think* clicking "Delete" does bring up a confirmation box. (The patch above does not implement one for audits, although it should be doable.) But for users who can only recommend deletion, there doesn't appear to be any confirmation step for questions at all.  Perhaps there should be?

Comment: Ps. Yes, I've tested the SOUP fix, and it works for me. I've never been quite so happy to (deliberately) fail a review audit before. ;-)

Comment: Please also note that the fix should be applied to all popup windows which can be canceled, not only the `recommend deletion` button. It should be also for `flag`, `comment`, `close vote`, etc.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy: AFAIK, closing and flagging (in queues that allow them) already wait for you to actually submit before triggering audit success/failure. It's only deletion in the LQP queue that short-circuits this.

Comment: I don't remember already, have too much ban for this :/