# Cheating in the review audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits

So while reviewing First Posts in the Review Queue, I sometimes open the Question in a new tab to get a context of what the Review Item really is. However, if the Review Item was an audit, I will realize it once I open the question in a new tab.

Of course If I realized it is an audit, I will upvote the post to pass the audit.

Isn't this considered cheating? I feel that opening the Review Item in a new tab is not wrong, but it has a side effect if the Review Item is an audit, so I'm torn.

What should I do in this case?

Comment: The general consensus seems to be that if you're going to the effort of opening in a new tab, you're ok.

Comment: It's not really "cheating" if you're investigating whether a question is truly off-topic. Doing this all the time. You often have to look at context to determine if something should be closed/reopened. Often it's even the answers which put questions over the off-topic edge.

Comment: So it's not cheating? Good to know. I somehow feel relieved.

Comment: Just a shameless plug, but if you find yourself going to the question page for more context often while reviewing, consider using [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup), which [shows answers directly on the review page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172931/please-put-answers-underneath-questions-in-close-review-queue) (and also [makes it slightly harder to fail LQP audits accidentally](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302336/dont-fail-lqp-review-audits-just-for-looking-at-the-deletion-popup)).