# Error in Low Quality Posts queue when recommending deletion

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits, low-quality-posts

I was presented with this review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9809226

I get the same error with this review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9809224

Obviously, that's not something that should remain, so I clicked "Recommend Deletion" then left the default "No comment needed" and pressed "Delete"

Nothing happened. It doesn't look like the it's processing (no processing bar, nothing appears in the browser status box).

When I press "Delete" a second time, I get sent to a Page Not found with my `fkey` in the URL:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32949605/recommend-delete?delete-main=&fkey=MY_FKEY_WAS_HERE
```

If I look at the History tab for the Queue, the review doesn't show. It also doesn't show in my [reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189134/andy?tab=activity) tab in my profile.

I didn't receive any error message during the review. It just looked like nothing happened.

Comment: Those are both audits; adding the [meta-tag:review-audits].

Comment: Also, are you by any chance using [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup)? There's an (apparently redundant -- I hadn't realized that SE had implemented this natively) fix for [this feature-req](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302336/dont-fail-lqp-review-audits-just-for-looking-at-the-deletion-popup) in SOUP that might be interfering here. Actually, I should make a point release to remove that fix anyway, since it's no longer needed.

Comment: As a follow-up to the previous comment above, SOUP v1.38.2 (and v1.39.3 on the devel branch) no longer includes the linked LQP review audit fix. I'm still not sure if this *is* a SOUP bug, but if it is, it should be fixed as soon as your SOUP version updates itself. (If it doesn't, you can do a manual update from Greasemonkey / Tampermonkey options, or by [clicking this link](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/raw/master/SOUP.user.js).)

Comment: I do use SOUP. I just updated and went through my reviews for the day. I didn't hit an audit where I should have deleted content, so I'm unable to tell if if that resolved the problem or not. I will update you after performing review tasks in the next couple days.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, It's been a little over a month and I haven't encountered the issue again. I assume that means it was SOUP related.