# Flag marked as helpful, but nothing done?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22391156/3204827) question as "All the comments on this question as in another language." so a mod would look at it instead of me flagging each comment (I think it is advised to do that if there are a few comments to be flagged, pretty sure I saw it on some question in this MSO). I flagged it on the 29th of May and the flag was changed to helpful a few days later. I know sometimes action mightn't be taken immediately due to paper work* mods have to do, but I didn't think take this long?

*I know mods probably don't have paper work, but it sounds good.

Answer (score 27):

I wasn't the moderator who processed the flag so I'm not sure exactly what happened. Your flag was:

> All the comments on this question as in another language.

The comments on the question were deleted when the flag was processed.  Unless the moderator knew to go in an look at every answer, I'm guessing that they didn't realize that all the comments for the entire post were in another language.  I've since deleted all of the comments on each answer as well.

My suggestion when using the custom "Other" flag would be to give as many details as possible - for example you could say "All comments on the question and answers are in a different language and should be deleted", then we will know to check the entire thing.

Comment: Mods seem to spend very little time per flag… Maybe we need more mods?

Comment: @bjb568 I disagree that we spend little time per flag. Part of the reason for our backlog (currently 1.4k+) is most flags require time to research.  The problem here is the flag wasn't detailed enough to accurately judge.  While I didn't process the flag it stated "The comments in the question", I probably wouldn't have reviewed the comments on the answers as well.

Comment: By too little time, I don't mean 30 second per CV (using that since I know about CVs, not mod flags) instead of 35 seconds. I mean going and VLQing, -1ing, commenting, [tag:cv-pls] on chat (in some cases), and voting on answers then after my review see how others reviewed it to check if they're robo-reviewing. That's how I review.

Comment: @bjb568 I have no idea what you are talking about in that comment.

Comment: I'm not talking about time. I'm talking about theroness.

Comment: @bjb568 We can only go off of what we are told in the flags.  As people say we are janitors, you have to let us know what we are supposed to clean up.  We can't read your minds.

Comment: Non-mods don't get *anything* to go off of. In the edit queue (which happens to be a "bad questions" queue too…) there's a change summary, but nobody puts anything meaningful in it. So I review the things [*independent*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251038/close-queue-audit-reviews-damn-you-too-quickly#comment2950_251400) of what other people think about it. I don't care whether people thot the question was bad, the answers are probably bad too.

Answer (score 11):

I was the one who acted on that flag. I think this was a simple misinterpretation.

What happened there was this: I saw your flag in the moderator queue, and read it to say that only the comments on the question needed to be cleaned up. When we see flagged questions in the moderator queue, we can expand them inline to show all comments.

I did that to clean up all the comments on the question. Since there were non-English comments there, I thought that was all you were referring to. I had no idea you meant that there were comments on the answers as well. We don't see answers in that view, so none of that was immediately obvious.

Generally, fights in comments, strings of non-English comments, etc. are almost always localized to a single post, so when you flagged that one I thought I only had to look at that. For things spanning multiple posts, it helps to call that out so that we know to look outside of our default views. That's why these other comments were missed.

Sorry about that.