# Correction comments to erroneous comments not appearing due to up-votes?

Tags: discussion

I came across this answer recently.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2624210/620863

It contained a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624192/good-hash-function-for-strings/2624210#comment92937392_2624210) that listed a pretty egregious short-coming.  I nearly dismissed the answer out of hand because of it, but then expanded the comment thread.  In it, there was a correction by the same commenter saying their first comment was incorrect.

However, due to how comment visibility works, only the first incorrect comment was visible.  (This may no longer be the case, as I up-voted the correction; at the time the first comment had +2 while the correction had 0)

Should this be addressed at all?  There's no good way for the answerer to address it, or the commenter without resorting to a delete, while third parties may exacerbate the issue instead of solve it if their up-votes are biased towards what is visible to them.  I don't have any suggestions, but just wanted to throw light on it.

Comment: considering neither comment are useful anymore, they should be deleted

Comment: I find it quite interesting that you would dismiss an answer with 174 upvotes out of hand, just because of a comment with 2 tiny-votes pointing out an issue. To answer your question, just flag those comments as NLN, and they'll be deleted.

Comment: @cigien - Most answers usually don't have that many upvotes, and comments can modify an answer's worth if you assume they're true.  For instance, it didn't say the answer was wrong, just that it wasn't ideal in a certain case.

Comment: It seems like this situation could be used as an example in the definition of what "No Longer Needed" flags are for. Admittedly, it would have been better if the users who posted the comments had cleaned them up themselves, but anyone reading the sequence of comments should recognize that the situation was fully and completely resolved and nobody interested in the answer ever needed to see or deal with those comments again (i.e. they have no net effect on the situation). That makes them classic "No Longer Needed" comments.

Answer (score -3):

The comment *itself* isn't searchable, and I have a really, really, *really* hard time trying to sympathize with anyone who thinks that a comment in an answer thread is what they should be reading *instead of an **answer***.

I'd be inclined to take no action on the comment, since the comment isn't actively against any rules, it's just...wrong.

Comment: I can't see what the comments said, but if I'm understanding the situation correctly, isn't this basically textbook No Longer Needed?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery OK, according to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259988/flag-marked-as-helpful-but-nothing-done/260102#260102) moderators can see all of the comments so a No Longer Needed might work, but I do remember some mods saying they prefer a Moderator Attention/Something Else flag if you want them to remove multiple ocmments.