# Can anything be done about older closeables now off the radar?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I happened to drift to this page ...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32579550/how-can-i-stop-my-buttons-disappearing-on-click-in-unity?rq=1

The QA is 1000% closeable - the OP simply had a totally unrelated typo "in another script",

there is absolutely no information on the page, whatsoever, of any value to any topic.

Trouble is, the page is incredibly old, so it would seem **unlikely many people will bother clicking close on it**.

I clicked close - but what can be done in this sort of situation?

(Is it the case perhaps that users with far more "points" than me can just instantly close and/or delete things like this, or is there a queue or something along the lines of "add a close vote to this if you agree it is ancient flotsam"?)

What's the deal here?

Every engineer is anal, every good engineer is very anal, and I lose sleep over things like this.  What to do?

---

Trying to parse Hans' comment below, I'll explain:

I was answering a question on here for a user.  It was about topic Unity3D blah blah.  I quickly searched for existing answers on SO about Unity3D blah blah.

So, there were say 4 relevant QA. However, 2 of them were of this "completely useless, nobody bothered to close at the time" variety.

You can see (Hans and others) it would be great if there was a way to bring to the attention of others (or - something) such older should-be-closed questions,

because they really use up time.  You can see that in my example, whilst trying to deal with a question / provide an answer, I had to sift through the 4 items .. 2 of them were a waste of time.

Indeed, is there a list somewhere of "questions recently got close votes?"  Maybe I could be doing more and I don't know it.

There are lots of queues on this site, like "approve edits" and so on.  Is there one along the lines "Maybe add a close vote to this" ..?

Comment: Hmya, there's another couple of million of those.  Losing sleep over them certainly solves the problem, we however strive to keep our users alive.  Just stop looking.  And please do us all a favor and add [unity*] to the ignored tags section in your profile.

Comment: Hi Hans - I don't totally follow your comment.  (Were you trying to be funny? It's unclear.)

Comment: Your question is unclear and irrelevant or not understandable from the question or from your description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> there is absolutely no information on the page, whatsoever, of any value to any topic.

That is a perfect reason to down vote. Remember that questions that have no answers and are not active will be deleted by the community user when the Roomba script runs. [*The system will automatically delete unlocked, unanswered questions that have negative score after 30 days.*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/158100)

In the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room we might handle old questions if they attract new (low quality) answers or if such questions are used as an example of *it is allowed to ask bad questions*. If you leave a message in the chatroom some of the regulars will help in making the best call of action.

Your close vote does end-up in the [close vote queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close). In popular tags you might get lucky that enough reviewers handle that review task and the question wil be closed (and deleted if it didn't get answered/accepted).

Keep in mind that not enough users are using all their close votes and flags so we rather focus on new and active stuff than on posts that do no active harm. I would love to see that differently but so far the non-close-voters didn't explain why they don't use their privilege to the full extent.

Comment: **"Remember that questions that have no answers and are not active will be deleted..."**  AHHHH .... awesome.  So indeed the answer here is really "be sure to downvote".  In a sense downvoting is more important, then, than clicking close?  Is my understanding correct?  thanks for this

Comment: ah there IS a close vote queue!  awesome ... like, where is that?  Should I be seeing it, for example, or is it only for staff?/whatever?

Comment: @JoeBlow Yes, I think down voting is under-appreciated as a very powerful moderation method, specially because so many users can do that as opposed to close voting which not only needs 3K or rep but also 5 fellow users.

Comment: *"so we rather focus on new and active stuff than on posts that do no active harm"* ... I guess that is coherent as a policy; funny, for me I'd rather dust out old stuff.  But sure, it makes sense as a policy.

Comment: The queues are [found here](http://stackoverflow.com/review)

Comment: I had utterly no understanding of the whole point of downvoting until you explained it just now.  I assumed it had no effect, whatsoever, other than social disapprobation.

Comment: **holy canoli!!!**  I've discovered the close queue.  This has to be the most informative answer ever on Meta.  Thanks - and I mean it!  Cheers!

Comment: Have fun in help close voting some of the stuff. Watch out for the [audits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251038/close-queue-audit-reviews-damn-you-too-quickly) and filter on your popular tag

Comment: I don't really understand that - but in any event, I naturally only click "Close" if it should be closed.  cheers again!